# python twisted : retrieve a deferred's execution time

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I would like to know how long a Deferred takes to execute, from the time the first callback is fired to the final result.

Any ideas on how to do that, possibly in a non-invasive manner ( meaning no modification on any of the callback functions in order to track the execution time ) ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are running your program with help of "twistd", then it has an option "--profile" which can help you with profiling twisted code.

```
twistd "other options" --profile=statsfile --profiler=cProfile --savestats
```

And to view the stats:

```
import pstats
stats = pstats.Stats('statsfile')
stats.sort_stats('time').print_stats()
```

Callbacks are executed immediately after the deferreds are fired.  But immediately means that each callback in the deferred chain has to be executed and they would have their own execution time. Also various pieces of code will have their own slice of time for execution including the reactor loop.

So to say the word - immediately is to say as soon as possible.

Consider the following bad example :

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
import time

def timeit(func):
    def wrapper(*arg):
        t1 = time.time()
        res = func(*arg)
        t2 = time.time()
        print '%s took %0.3f ms' % (func.func_name, (t2-t1)*1000.0)
        return res
    return wrapper

d = defer.Deferred()

@timeit
def callfunc1(result):
    print 'XXXXX'

@timeit   
def callfunc2(result):
    print 'YYYYY'

d.addCallback(callfunc1)   
d.addCallback(callfunc2)  
t1 = time.time()
d.callback(True)
t2 = time.time()
print '%0.3f ms' % ((t2-t1)*1000.0)
```

Output:

```
XXXXX
callfunc1 took 0.039 ms
YYYYY
callfunc2 took 0.005 ms
0.108 ms
```

Now if we tweak the above code to include a reactor and callLater

Answer (score 3):

Guess you should profile your app, follow this way:

install this tool http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html

fire your twisted app and collect raw data:

> twistd --savestats -n --profile=myapp.hotshot myapp

than, you convert 'hotshot' to 'calltree', run:

> hotshot2cg myapp.hotshot > myapp.calltree

now we can view calltree in Kcachegrind tool.

> kcachegrind myapp.calltree

with this tool you can view the call-graph of twisted event loop,
execution time you can see in percents.
so no need to patching the code, just run this tool and see

P.S. for checking the memory: 
[How to use guppy/heapy for tracking down memory usage](https://bitbucket.org/osunix/ospkg/src/3aad1843cdd7/dev-notes/heapy.rst)

Comment: What provides the hotshot2cg command?  I can't find any mention of it in pip or brew & no mention online either....

Comment: hotshot2cg is like a converter and is a part of KCacheGrind app, so it should be installed first.

Comment: I was not able to run hotshot2cg, even after installing kcache grind. I was unableable to find any algorithm/software to convert hotshot to calltree. Downvote.

Comment: @WaxCage The command is 'hotshot2calltree'. Anyway, hotshot (format) seems outdated, replaced by pstats, which is what cProfile now gives you. You can convert that with [pyprof2calltree](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyprof2calltree).

Answer (score 1):

Profiling is a bit overkill for what I'd like to achieve.

I ended up with a solution that didn't imply heavy modifications on existing code, but is in no way "universal" :

my original code was something like :

```
def myfunc(*args):
    d = Deferred()
    d.addCallback(cb1)
    ...
    d.addCallback(lambda x: MyObject(x))
```

I now have:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    init_time = time.time()
    d = Deferred()
    d.addCallback(cb1)
    ...
    d.addCallback(lambda x: MyObject(x, init_time))

class MyObject:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        ...
        self.exec_time = time.time() - init_time
```

It does just what I want, but I was hoping the Deferred structure would expose something keeping track of the execution time itself, instead of having to tinker with my objects. From the source code, I can see no such thing is available : http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-10.0.0/twisted/internet/defer.py#L137

Comment: @user304965: I was hesitant to give an answer like this, primarily due to fact that you have to instrument your callbacks for profiling. This is possible if you are writing your own code. Still it is ugly to instrument code for this purpose. But if you are using callbacks from other's module, you can not even do that. Idea is that callbacks will fire immediately but that depends on many things going around.